# Stopping position:fixed div at certain point (before footer starts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem has been discussed on the forum a few times however I cannot make it work so I ask for help.

I have a side contact menu (as a widget) in my WP website and made it position: fixed so it doesn't change position during scrolling. However, I want it to stop being fixed before it hits footer div because it just looks weird.

As far as I read I need jquery and a script that changes my fixed position to a relative at some point so I feel like I understand the basic mechanic of it and even found several scripts but all of them doesn't work at all.

I want something exactly like in here: 
[Stop fixed position at certain div or certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328251/stop-fixed-position-at-certain-div-or-certain-position)

I created 3 files: html, css, js and put all the codes from the answer and it just does not work at all..

My js file - java.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var navTop = $('#nav').offset().top;
var navStop = $('#stop').offset().top;
var lastMode = "absolute";

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var mode;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= navTop) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() - navStop + $('#nav').height() > 0)
      mode = 'absolute';
    else
      mode = 'fixed';
  } else {
    mode = 'absolute';
  }

  if (lastMode !== mode) {
    if (mode == 'fixed') {
      $('#nav').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#nav').css('top', '0');
    } else {
      $('#nav').css('position', 'absolute');
      $('#nav').css('top', navTop);
    }
    lastMode = mode;
  }
});

}
```

My css file- style.css:

```
#nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

#stop {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 900px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

My html doc - index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="java.js"></script>
<body style="height:5000px;">
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="stop"></div>
</body>
```

Since the code above is just an answer from another topic - I wanted to change it for my needs but it seems I do something wrong because it does not work.

To detail: I want side contact menu `<div class="widget-contact">` to start normally like it is right now (position fixed) and stop it from being fixed when it hits 
`<div id="colophon-inside" class="footer-three">`

I am fine using html/css however I do not understand js and I feel my problem is quite easy to solve.

Could you help?

Comment: I do not feel like looking into your code, but you could try `position: sticky`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to do it this way as well and even tried it but when I change position to sticky in WP CSS editor, I got the message that it looks for a relative | absolute | fixed | static position and do not know the sticky one. After ignoring it and saving css, it just starts to be static instead of sticky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. You just missed out a ")" at the end of your javascript file. So completing your JS file it should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var navTop = $('#nav').offset().top;
var navStop = $('#stop').offset().top;
var lastMode = "absolute";

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var mode;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= navTop) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() - navStop + $('#nav').height() > 0)
      mode = 'absolute';
    else
      mode = 'fixed';
  } else {
    mode = 'absolute';
  }

  if (lastMode !== mode) {
    if (mode == 'fixed') {
      $('#nav').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#nav').css('top', '0');
    } else {
      $('#nav').css('position', 'absolute');
      $('#nav').css('top', navTop);
    }
    lastMode = mode;
  }
});

})
```

Here I say this is "Solved"

Comment: Could you please try it out and if it works, .zip files in one directory and upload it? I would download and just compare code mark by mark to understand why it still doesnt work

Comment: It works on jsfiddle. I got the code from there but when I paste it into .html .css .js documents and upload it on the server or try to open the file locally it does not work -.-

Comment: I've sent you a HTML file using drive. That file also works locally. You can refer to that

Comment: Thank you! It works now, I just sent the previous comment before refreshing page with your answer. I cannot understand what I did wrong. You put it all in 1 document as in-lines so I thought I messed up with files connection but then I moved JS code from your document to js file and it still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/42muhgj3/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const pos = Math.max(5, 200 - $(this).scrollTop());
  // maximum 200, minimum 5, according to scrollTop
  $('#nav').css('top', pos + 'px');
  console.log(pos);
});
```

css

```css
#nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: sticky;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```